# How to add years to date in Hiveql

Tags: hiveql

Hive query equivalent of T-SQL Statement SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, '2019/05/25') ?

I am aware add_months() works for adding months to a given date. Now i am looking for adding years to a date.

Thanks

Comment: You can add 12 month

Answer (score 0):

Try the functions `years_add(timestamp date, int years)` or `years_sub(timestamp date, int years)` which are mentioned in cloudera's latest documentation.

If this solutions doesn't work, you can still try using `add_months()` and multiply your desired number of years by 12 to add the correct number of months.

Hope this helps !